# check if string contains dictionary Key -> remove key and add value

Tags: c#, linq, generic-collections

I am stuck at a function which checks a string ('14534000000875e') if it contains a letter.
If it contains a letter (a-z), remove the letter and add a string to the end.

To realize this, I have created a `Dictionary<char, string>` Pairs which has mapped a to 09001, b to 09002 [...] and z to 09026

This is my code so far:

```
public static string AlterSerial(string source)
{
    Dictionary<char, string> pairs = new Dictionary<char, string>();
    pairs.Add('a', "09001");
    ...

    int index = source.IndexOf(x);
    if (index != -1)
    {
        return source.Remove(index, 1);
    }
    return source;
}
```

How can I check if the `source` string contains one of the 26 keys, delete this key and add the corresponding string to the end of the source-string?

**Note: the letter is not always at the end of the source.**

Kind regards

Comment: What if string contains the same letter more than once?

Comment: what's wrong with String.Replace("a","09001"), etc?

Comment: Will the letter always be at the end of the string?

Comment: Will there just be a single letter involved, or is this possible:  `14g534b00a00c008sd75e`?  If so, what happens?  Do they get replaced "in order" (dictionary) or randomly, or what...?

Comment: There is only ONE letter. It is mostly at the end but not always.

Comment: @Jonesy - I think the string gets appended to the end, so `Replace` won't cut it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dictionary<char, string> pairs = new Dictionary<char, string>();
pairs.Add('a', "09001");
...

foreach(KeyValuePair<string, string> entry in pairs)
{
    if (source.Contains(entry.Key))  // .Key must be capitalized
    {
      source = source.Replace(entry.Key, "") + entry.Value;
      break;
    }
}

return source;
....
```

Comment: Don't forget that there are 26 characters, and that for each of them you need to check if the string contains it and if it does, to replace it. shouldn't it be better to see if there is a letter and then if there is, replace it from the dictionary.

Comment: Yes even i was going to type the same logic ... the algorithm of Nikola would generally tend to be faster...

Comment: what is 'source' ?

Answer (score 4):

So this is the solution where you have only one letter within your string. You need to find the letter that is within the string, if it exists, and find its index. Then you have to insert the respective value instead of the letter, obtained from the dictionary.

```
String mystring = "1453400e0000875";
Dictionary<char, string> pairs = new Dictionary<char, string>();
pairs.Add('a', "09001");
pairs.Add('b', "09002");
pairs.Add('c', "09003");
pairs.Add('d', "09004");
pairs.Add('e', "09005");
//...
char letter = mystring.FirstOrDefault(a => Char.IsLetter(a));
if (letter != '\0')
{
      int index = mystring.IndexOf(letter);
      string substitute;
      pairs.TryGetValue(mystring[index], out substitute);
      mystring = mystring.Substring(0, index) + substitute + mystring.Substring(index + 1);
}
```

EDIT:
Using Replace method of the string, the `if` part can be altered like this:

```
char letter = mystring.FirstOrDefault(a => Char.IsLetter(a));
if (letter != '\0')
{
       string substitute;
       pairs.TryGetValue(letter, out substitute);
       mystring = mystring.Replace(letter.ToString(), substitute);
}
```

EDIT2:And if I didn't understand the OP correctly so that he wants to remove the letter and add the replacement string to the end of the source string, the `if` statement should be like this:

```
if (letter != '\0')
{
       string substitute;
       pairs.TryGetValue(letter, out substitute);
       mystring = mystring.Replace(letter.ToString(), "");
       mystring += substitute;
}
```

and this is the generalisation when you have more letters within the string. It is the similar solution but requires to iterate over all the letters within the string.

```
String mystring = "1453a400e0000b875";
Dictionary<char, string> pairs = new Dictionary<char, string>();
pairs.Add('a', "09001");
pairs.Add('b', "09002");
pairs.Add('c', "09003");
pairs.Add('d', "09004");
pairs.Add('e', "09005");
//...
var lettersList = mystring.Where(a => Char.IsLetter(a));
foreach (char letter in lettersList)
{
        int index = mystring.IndexOf(letter);
        string substitute;
        pairs.TryGetValue(mystring[index], out substitute);
        mystring = mystring.Substring(0, index) + substitute + mystring.Substring(index + 1);
}
```

Checked and it works!

Comment: Yes, I just wanted to handle the other possible cases.

Comment: It's not a bad solution but it does specifically say to add to the end of the string in the question. Waiting for clarification...

Comment: @DaveWilliams The OP specifically said in the comments "There is only ONE letter. It is mostly at the end but not always". the later solution is just for any case.

Comment: Quote "How can I check if the source string contains one of the 26 keys, delete this key and add the corresponding string to the **end** of the source-string?"

Comment: I have tested both proposed solutions. both work, so both get an upvote. But 'unlimit's solutions looks far more elegant, so he'll get the answer mark.
Thank you for helping

Comment: You're welcome, You just need to think about the effectiveness. However suits you!

Answer (score 2):

Nikola's answer is good and if you like it you should mark it as the answer. However I like this simple method (slightly borrowed a few things :p).

```
var Alphabet = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz".ToArray();

var Pairs = new Dictionary<char, string>();
for(var i = 1; i < Alphabet.Count() +1; i++)
    Pairs.Add(Alphabet[i-1], "090" + (i < 10 ? "0" + i.ToString() : i.ToString()));

var Source = "14534000000875e";

var Chars = Source.Where(x => Char.IsLetter(x));
var Output = string.Empty();

foreach(var Char in Chars)
    Output = Source.Replace(Char.ToString(), Pairs[Char]);
```

or if you want the replacement at the end and only once for repeated chars?

```
foreach(var Char in Chars)
Output = Source.Replace(Char.ToString(),"") + (Pairs[Char]);
```