# check if string contains dictionary keys and replace the matching subtring with Values from dictionary

Tags: c#

I am parsing a template file which will contain certain keys that I need to map values to. Take a line from the file for example:

```
Field InspectionStationID 3 {"PVA TePla #WSM#", "sw#data.tool_context.TOOL_SOFTWARE_VERSION#", "#data.context.TOOL_ENTITY#"}
```

I need to replace the string within the # symbols with values from a dictionary.
So there can be multiple keys from the dictionary. However, not all strings inside the # are in the dictionary so for those, I will have to replace them with empty string.

I cant seem to find a way to do this. And yes I have looked at this solution:
[check if string contains dictionary Key -> remove key and add value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17191451/check-if-string-contains-dictionary-key-remove-key-and-add-value)

For now what I have is this (where I read from the template file line by line and then write to a different file):

```
string line = string.Empty;
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
            { "data.tool_context.TOOL_SOFTWARE_VERSION", "sw0.2.002" },
            {"data.context.TOOL_ENTITY", "WSM102" }


        };
StringBuilder inputText = new StringBuilder();
StreamWriter writeKlarf = new StreamWriter(klarfOutputNameActual); 
using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(WSMTemplatePath)) 
{
    while((line = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        //Console.WriteLine(line);
        if (line.Contains("#"))
        {

        

        }
        else
        {
            writeKlarf.WriteLine(line)
        }
        
    }
}
writeKlarf.Close();
```

THe idea is that for each line, replace the string within the # and the # with match values from the dictionary if the  #string# is inside the dictionary. How can I do this?

Sample Output Given the line above:

```
Field InspectionStationID 3 {"PVA TePla", "sw0.2.002", "WSM102"}
```

Here because #WSM# is not the dictionary, it is replaced with empty string

One more thing, this logic only applies to the first qurter of the file. The rest of the file will have other data that will need to be entered via another logic so I am not sure if it makes sense to read the whole file in into memory just for the header section?

Comment: Can you provide a complete example of a given input and expectd output? And how do you decide wheter to "leave it as it is" or "replace with an empty string"?

Comment: @derpirscher done

Comment: Where is the dictionary? And you didn't explain this sentence "*However, not all strings inside the # are in the dictionary so for those, I will have to either leave as is or replace them with empty string.*" how do you decice whether to replace with empty or leave as is?

Comment: @derpirscher modified for clarity. Thank you for your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quick example that I wrote for you, hopefully this is what you're asking for.

This will let you have a <string, string> Dictionary, check for the Key inside of a delimiter, and if the text inside of the delimiter matches the Dictionary key, it will replace the text. It won't edit any of the inputted strings that don't have any matches.

If you want to delete the unmatched value instead of leaving it alone, replace the `kvp.Value` in the `line.Replace()` with `String.Empty`

```
var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    { "test", "cool test" }
};

string line = "#test# is now replaced.";

foreach (var kvp in dict)
{
    string split = line.Split('#')[1];
    if (split == kvp.Key)
    {
        line = line.Replace($"#{split}#", kvp.Value);
    }

    Console.WriteLine(line);
}

Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: What does the [1] in the split line do? Sorry I'm new to c#

Comment: Access the second element of the resulting array?

Comment: @dozie419 it will just access the second item in the array. String.Split() will create an array (the 0 index being the text BEFORE the first occurrence of the delimiter (# in your case), and the 1 index being the text that appears immediately after the first delimiter, which is the text you are wanting to check and replace.

Comment: @kasprdev thank you. I have edited the question for better clarity as well!

Answer (score 0):

If you had a list of tuple that were the find and replace, you can read the file, replace each, and then rewrite the file

```
var frs = new List<(string F, string R)>(){
  ("#data.tool_context.TOOL_SOFTWARE_VERSION#", "sw0.2.002"),
  ("#otherfield#", "replacement here")
};

var i = File.ReadAllText("path");
frs.ForEach(fr => i = i.Replace(fr.F,fr.R));
File.WriteAllText("path2", i);
```

The choice to use a list vs dictionary is fairly arbitrary; List has a ForEach method but it could just as easily be a foreach loop on a dictionary. I included the ## in the find string because I got the impression the output is *not* supposed to contain ##..

This version leaves alone any template parameters that aren't available

Comment: One more thing, this logic only applies to the first qurter of the file. The rest of the file will have other data that will need to be entered via another logic so I am not sure if it makes sense to read the whole file in into memory just for the header section? I guess I am thinking about time complexity as well

Answer (score 0):

You can try *matching* `#...#` keys with a help of *regular expressions*:

```
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

  ...
         
static string MyReplace(string value, IDictionary<string, string> subs) => Regex
  .Replace(value, "#[^#]*#", match => subs.TryGetValue(
     match.Value.Substring(1, match.Value.Length - 2), out var item) ? item : "");
```

then you can apply it to the file: we read file's lines, process them with a help of *Linq* and write them into another file.

```
  var dict = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
    {"data.tool_context.TOOL_SOFTWARE_VERSION", "sw0.2.002" },
    {"data.context.TOOL_ENTITY",                "WSM102"    },
  };

  File.WriteAllLines(klarfOutputNameActual, File
    .ReadLines(WSMTemplatePath)
    .Select(line => MyReplace(line, dict)));
```

**Edit:** If you want to *switch off* `MyReplace` from some line on

```
  bool doReplace = true;

  File.WriteAllLines(klarfOutputNameActual, File
    .ReadLines(WSMTemplatePath)
    .Select(line => {
       //TODO: having line check if we want to keep replacing
       if (!doReplace || SomeCondition(line)) {
         doReplace = false;

         return line;
       }

       return MyReplace(line, dict)
     }));
```

Here `SomeCondition(line)` returns `true` whenever header ends and we should not replace `#..#` any more.

Comment: One more thing, this logic only applies to the first qurter of the file. The rest of the file will have other data that will need to be entered via another logic so I am not sure if it makes sense to read the whole file in into memory just for the header section? I guess I am thinking about time complexity as well

Comment: @dozie419: my code reads the file *line after line* (`File.ReadLines(WSMTemplatePath)`), that's why it requires memory for a file's *single line* only. If I understand you right, you want to write *entire* file to `klarfOutputNameActual` that's why we have to read (line by line) entire `WSMTemplatePath` file as well